# How are rs1 & rs2 fields for floating point registers (f0-f31) encoded in RISC-V Instructions?

Tags: floating-point, disassembly, riscv

The Integer register encoding corresponds to their numeric names (0-31, for x0-x31). What is this encoding for f0-f31?

I am trying to write a disassembler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floating-point registers are encoded in the same way. The processor knows whether to use an integer register or a floating-point register by the nature of the instruction.

RISC-V specifications are at https://riscv.org/specifications/. As a sample for one type of instruction, in *The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual, Volume I: User Level ISA*, version 2.2, May 7, 2017, section 8.6, “Single-Precision Floating-Point Computational Instructions” says:

> Floating-point arithmetic instructions with one or two source operands use the R-type format with the OP-FP major opcode. FADD.S, FSUB.S, FMUL.S, and FDIV.S perform single-precision floating-point addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, respectively, between *rs1* and *rs2*, writing the result to *rd*.

The R-type format is shown in 2.2, “Base Instruction Formats.” A diagram there shows *rs1*, *rs2*, and *rd* are bits 19 through 15, 24 through 20, and 11 through 7, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

So a few things 1) there are the risc-v docs.  2) if you are writing the first assembler or disassembler for an instruction set then you work there and you can just go down one of the silicon engineers cubes and ask. 3) if not then there exists tools for this instruction set and you should use them as a reference:

Taking the risc-v docs:

```
.word 0x001100D3
.word 0x002100D3
.word 0x003100D3
.word 0x001100D3
.word 0x001200D3
.word 0x001300D3
.word 0x00130153
.word 0x00130253
.word 0x00130353
```

assemble then disassemble

```
   0:   001100d3            fadd.s  f1,f2,f1,rne
   4:   002100d3            fadd.s  f1,f2,f2,rne
   8:   003100d3            fadd.s  f1,f2,f3,rne
   c:   001100d3            fadd.s  f1,f2,f1,rne
  10:   001200d3            fadd.s  f1,f4,f1,rne
  14:   001300d3            fadd.s  f1,f6,f1,rne
  18:   00130153            fadd.s  f2,f6,f1,rne
  1c:   00130253            fadd.s  f4,f6,f1,rne
  20:   00130353            fadd.s  f6,f6,f1,rne
```

then write code using the mnemonics, repeat.  Develop your disassembler from the ISA documentation in combination with the existing tools, rotate through this process until you feel pretty good about your tool.  Expect errors or vagueness in the documentation...

Now of course in this case one hopes that gnu using an assembly language that somewhat resembles that of the risc-v folks desires, examples, documentation.  GNU has a habit of not doing that.  At the same time if you are writing a disassembler and not an assembler nor full toolchain then you should make the disassembler match the syntax of the assembler you are using, for your own sanity...

Comment: as Eric pointed answered, and in general (although there may be exceptions) most instruction sets that have registers numbered from 0 to n-1 the register number is what is encode r0-r7 you put a 0 to 7 in the three bit field 0-15 you put a 0 to 0xF in the field 0 to 31 you put a 0 to 0x1F in the field and so on.  Check this with an existing assembler or disassembler or source code to the chip if you have one or work there, etc...For risc-v there are many open source simulators and HDL to examine to confirm the encoding.